# How to open new browser tab using Selenium and Java by passing ChromeOptions to ChromeDriver?

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to create a variable that I can open a new tab with by using the code below in my Test:

```
getWebDriver().get("first website");
WebDriver newTab = getWebDriver().switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.TAB);
    newTab.get("second website");
```

Each test extends my GoogleChromeDriver class located in my test folder for which I have used ChromeOptions. The newTab variable works as expected and opens a new tab when using `setWebDriver(new ChromeDriver());`, but gives an error when passing options variable from ChromeOptions to it like `setWebDriver(new ChromeDriver(options));`

This is the `@BeforeTest` from my GoogleChromeDriver class

```
public void init() {
    List<String> driverArguments = List.of("disable-extensions", "profile-directory=Default", "incognito", "disable-plugins-discovery", "start-maximized");
    String currentUserDirectory = System.getProperty("user.home");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", currentUserDirectory + "\\Documents\\webDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", new String[]{"enable-automation"});
    options.addArguments(driverArguments);
    setWebDriver(new ChromeDriver());
}
```

This is the error I receive

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Failed to open new tab - no browser is open"}
```

UPDATE:
I have removed the `incognito` parameter from the list of options and it works now. Any ideas on how to open a new tab by using incognito tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the workaround solution. Am calling it a workaround solution as am not using the selenium's way of opening a new tab [`getWebDriver().switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.TAB);`]

Check the below solution using `Robot` class:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("incognito=new");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.url.com");
        
Robot rb = new Robot();
// Press control keyboard key
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
// Press T keyboard key
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
// Release control keyboard key
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
// Release T keyboard key
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
```

**Warning:** This solution using Robot class may not work in headless mode.